# Downgrading MySQL 5.5 > 5.1 - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server running MySQL 5.5.

How can I install MySQL 5.1 or 5.0 on it?

I have tried some commands:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
apt-get install mysql-server
```

None worked...I googled for hints, but no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by STEVEN MARTIN (MySQL expert)

1º Step:

Completely remove old mysql installation:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common
```

2º Step:

[Download MySQL 4.1 sources](http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/source/4.1/mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz) in order to build it and install.

```
wget http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/source/4.1/mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz
```

3º Step:

Run these commands to uncompress and build sources and then install:

```
sudo tar -xvzf mysql-4.1.24.tar.gz --directory=/usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src/mysql-4.1.24/
sudo groupadd mysql
sudo useradd -g mysql mysql
sudo apt-get install
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
sudo make
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/include
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/lib
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/share
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/man
sudo mkdir /usr/local/mysql/mysql-test
sudo checkinstall
    y
    mysql-server 4.1.24
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
sudo cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
cd /usr/local/mysql/
pwd
bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
sudo chown -R root .
sudo chown -R mysql var
sudo chgrp -R mysql .
bin/mysql --version
bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
sudo bin/mysqld_safe user=mysql &
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the currently installed version and download version 5.1 from [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.1).

Comment: How to uninstall?

Comment: @Darkeden with apt-get remove

Comment: I did removed as you told me ... Now at the installation step I get this error: Installing MySQL system tables...
130208 12:42:12 [ERROR] An old style --language value with language specific part detected: /usr/share/mysql/english/
130208 12:42:12 [ERROR] Use --lc-messages-dir without language specific part instead.

Comment: @Darkeden googling around a bit I've found this page, which you might find useful: http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/12bcgmxp4v/mysqld-cannot-start

Comment: Useless...I need a proper guide for completely unninstalling MySQL 5.5 and then installing 5.1

Comment: @Darkeden you could also use google a bit more though, anyway here you go: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1804209